# Dangers of dynamically modifying entity Model in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a class from which all my entity definitions inherit:

```
class Model(db.Model):
    """Superclass for all others; contains generic properties and methods."""

    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

For various reasons I want to be able to **occasionally** modify an entity without changing its modified property. I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Z_usJ1Cyntw) example:

```
Model.__dict__["modified"].__dict__["auto_now"] = False
db.put(my_entity)
Model.__dict__["modified"].__dict__["auto_now"] = True
```

When I test this locally, it works great. My question is this: **could this have wider ramifications for any other code that happens to be saving entities during the small period of time `Model` is altered?** I could see that leading to incredibly confusing bugs. But maybe this little change only affects the current process/thread or whatever?

Comment: You need to be aware that any other request coming in to the same instance and being handled whilst the put is in progress, will also get `auto_now=False`, whilst unlikely it is possible

Comment: If you don't have try block around it, then a timeout or error could leave it in the modified state.  Personally in think its a bad idea, and I question the design that needs such a hack.

Comment: As a strategy to achieve this without manipulating models, consider setting the default behaviour to auto_now=False, and then have to methods you use for updating. The primary method sets the modified time to datetime.now() just before you do the put(), the other method doesn't.  You could even override put() in your class, then set modified and then call super put()

Comment: Tim, this is all useful information. I would vote up a/o accept your answer if you took it out of the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any other request coming in to the same **instance** and being handled whilst the put is in progress will also get `auto_now=False`, whilst unlikely it is possible

Something else other thing to consider

You don't have `try` block around this code, if you get a timeout or error during the `put()` your code will leave the model in the modified state with `auto_now=False` .

Personally in think its a bad idea and will definatley be a source of errors.

There are a number of ways of achieving this without manipulating models,

consider setting the default behaviour to auto_now=False, and then have two methods you use for updating. The primary method sets the modified time to datetime.now() just before you do the put(), e.g save() and save_without_modified()

A better method would to override put() in your class, then set modified and then call super put() have put() accept a new argument like `modified=False` so you don't set the modified date before you call super.

Lastly you could use `_pre_put` hook to run code before the put() call, but you need to annotate the instance in some way so the `_pre_put` method can determine if modified needs to be set or not.

I think each of these strategies is a lot more safe than hacking the model